# Sklearn Pipeline to add new features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Say I have a dataset with a bunch of numerical features. I'm not sure what's the best way to use the numerical features in a model so I decide to apply different transformations to them and add those results to the dataset. These transformation could be MinMax Scaling, StandardScaling, LogTransform, ... whatever you can think of.

So basically, in the raw data I might only have the feature "Value_in_Dollars" and after all transformations I also want to have the transformed features in the dataset:

```
"Value_in_Dollars_MinMax", "Value_in_Dollars_SS", "Value_in_Dollars_Log"
```

in addition to the original column.

I know how to do this manually but how would I do this in a Sklearn pipeline? It this even possible?

Comment: you can try using the output from 'named_steps' and add the transformed value to the dataset in the manner you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FeatureUnion` and probably `ColumnTransformer`, e.g.

```py
union = FeatureUnion([("MinMax", MinMaxScaler()),
                      ("SS", StandardScaler()),
                      ("Log", FunctionTransformer(np.log1p)])
proc = ColumnTransformer([('trylots', union, ['Value_In_Dollars'])],
                         remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: Nice, I'm curious how this all would look wrapped up into one pipeline. Would that work?

Comment: And, is there a way to create custom transforms that create a new feature from within a single pipeline? Something like `pipeline([('make_bin', lambda x: 0 if x < 5 else 1)])`.

Comment: To your first question, yes, you can use `proc` as a step in a pipeline.  Your second seems like it should be a new Question, except that it's readily answered by the documentation:  have a look at `FunctionTransformer`, possibly together with the ideas here.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out. I figured I would find it with more searching, but I thought it might be useful to the community to put a bread crumb here, too.

Comment: when using `lambda: ...` in pipeline steps, may run into issues when the trained model needs to be persisted using pickle-like methods as those don't play well with lambda functions